# MYSQL: Using DAYNAME() to get data for the nearest date to today

Tags: php, mysql

In my mySQL db, I have a column called 'day'. Each training session has a different day - for this example, U12s has one on Tuesday and Thursday. What I want, is to get the data for the closest session (right now, that'd be Tuesday).

```
SELECT * 
  FROM training 
 WHERE `day` > dayname(now()) 
   AND `group` = 'U12s' 
 ORDER by `day` 
 LIMIT 1
```

This brings up a result, but it is sorting 'day' alphabetically, so the result is Thursday instead of Tuesday.

I also tried

```
SELECT * 
  FROM training 
 WHERE `day` > dayofweek(CURDATE()) 
   AND `group` = 'U12s' 
 LIMIT 1
```

but that brought up no results at all.

Any suggestions?

JorgeCampos' solution & syntax error:

```
                 SELECT * 
              FROM training 
             WHERE `day` > dayname(now()) 
               AND `group` = 'U12s' 
             ORDER BY CASE when `day` = 'Monday' then 1
                           when `day` = 'Tuesday' then 2
                           when `day` = 'Wednesday' then 3
                           when `day` = 'Thursday' then 4
                           when `day` = 'Friday' then 5
                           when `day` = 'Saturday' then 6
                           else 7 end case
             LIMIT 1
```

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case
 LIMIT 1' at line 11

Comment: What's the value in `day`? dayname returns a string, so you'd be trying to do `Wednesday > Sunday`, which is **TRUE**, because they're strings, and by string comparison rules, `W` comes after `S`, so it's greater

Comment: ^ Agreed, and if you can, don't store "derived" data in the db.  In this case, the string name of the day is derived from the day of week which can be better found via the date.  Your frontend interfaces would be very capable of translating the date, into day of week, into the string name, at presentation time..

Comment: @MarcB the values in 'day' are Monday, Tuesday, etc

Comment: then you should store them as dayofweek values instead. 1=Sunday, 2=Monday, etc... numbers you can compare easily. strings, not so much.

Comment: @Lance the dates are set, they don't change, so they wouldn't be something like 31/07/2015 01/08/2015 etc.. would this still work?

Comment: @MarcB how would I go about getting the row for the closest date using that method?

Comment: ``order by abs(`storedayofweek` - dayofweek(now())) asc``.

Comment: @HandsomeJack you need the dates, or a very very fancy query.  If you had the actual date, which you could easily insert with a loop, then you could simply use a query of SELECT * FROM training WHERE `day` > NOW() && `group`='U12s' LIMIT 1

Comment: @MarcB I still don't understand how that'd work?

Comment: you should just be storing the actual date for the sessions. then it's `where sessiondate > now()`

Answer (score 0):

If your day column is the name of the days and your query is already ok but the order is wrong you just need to convert the day for a value that can be ordered as you need so:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM training 
 WHERE `day` > dayname(now()) 
   AND `group` = 'U12s' 
 ORDER BY CASE when `day` = 'Monday' then 1
               when `day` = 'Tuesday' then 2
               ....
               when `day` = 'Saturday' then 6
               else 7 end
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when I try this but I'm not sure why?

Comment: The problem with this, and the OP query is that it is trying to guess the "next" day of week, so on Friday the "next Tuesday" needs to come up, which has a lower number than dayname(now()).  Is there a way to use str_to_date("the next day in this week or first day of next week",format) where "next...." is derived from the existing field value?

Comment: @Lance well there is a way, but I chosed to just fix the OP query since he said that is ok on his question.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I personally would love to see that query :)  I am impressed by the ORDER BY CASE solution, which is beautiful by the way.

Comment: @JorgeCampos the error I get is "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' when `day` = 'Tuesday' then 2, when `day` = 'Wedn' at line 5"

Comment: @Lance the variation would not be difficult. Imagene the same query of the OP and the `case statement` as a field so you would make this query as a subquery twice and then join then two with the id (whatever it is) and make a condition `query1.day < query2.day` hope you hjave understanded.

Comment: @HandsomeJack can you create a sqlfidlle with your query so I can see it? http://sqlfiddle.com just hit the button Build Schema then past your query and hit the run sql button. Copy the link and past it here

Comment: @JorgeCampos I get an error there too - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case
 LIMIT 1' at line 11

Comment: @JorgeCampos I can't build a schema because of the error, but I will add it to the OP so you can see the SQL and error

Comment: @HandsomeJack sorry the error was on the `end case` the right way is just `end` I already updated my answer.

Comment: @JorgeCampos spoke too soon. This works, but only in certain cases. Example: If there are results for Tuesday and Thursday, this brings up Tuesday, BUT, if I make it Sunday and Tuesday, it still brings up Tuesday. I'm guessing this is because of the way the numbers are assigned to each, any idea how to fixthat ?

Comment: Is that because I started the week with monday? Because if it is you just have to reorder the elements on the case statement. Starting your week as sunday = 1. Here in Brazil we consider the week start as monday im most cases.